# Tag for placeholder pages ("under construction", "under development", "coming soon", …)

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it would be useful to have a tag for placeholder pages, i.e., pages that are "under development", announce a launch ("coming soon"), or show one of those [classy construction GIFs](http://www.textfiles.com/underconstruction/asashleyatucsbunder-construction.gif) like it’s 1995.

Quick list of example questions (no detail check done yet, will be done before possibly adding the tag):

- [Should I block crawling on my site until it's finished?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113748/should-i-block-crawling-on-my-site-until-its-finished)
- [Should I notify 'under construction' websites to crawlers? If yes how?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28819/should-i-notify-under-construction-websites-to-crawlers-if-yes-how)
- [Does a 'Under Construction' notice impacts site ranking negatively?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/does-a-under-construction-notice-impacts-site-ranking-negatively)
- [Under construction page bad for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104194/under-construction-page-bad-for-seo)
- [default namecheap "under construction" homepage and SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68017/default-namecheap-under-construction-homepage-and-seo)
- [Is it wise to use a country-based tld when a .com already exists, but is "Under Construction"?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20892/is-it-wise-to-use-a-country-based-tld-when-a-com-already-exists-but-is-under)
- [Redirect all traffic to construction page except my IP in .htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/redirect-all-traffic-to-construction-page-except-my-ip-in-htaccess)
- [How to prevent Google (and others) from indexing the site under construction?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57886/how-to-prevent-google-and-others-from-indexing-the-site-under-construction)
- ["Coming soon" pages & SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/coming-soon-pages-seo)
- [Should I create a 'Website coming soon' page for my recently-acquired domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89549/should-i-create-a-website-coming-soon-page-for-my-recently-acquired-domain)

I’ll be happy to add the tag (and apply other needed edits), but **what name should it have?**

[placeholder-page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placeholder-page) (but sometimes there are also placeholder *sites*), [under-construction](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/under-construction), [under-development](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/under-development), [coming-soon](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coming-soon), …?

---

For short-lived pages (e.g., while installing updates), we have the tag [site-maintenance](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-maintenance).

For launching (again), we have the tag [launch](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launch).

Comment: I might consider two tags because "coming soon" seems like a special case of "under construction".  Although it seems like all your example questions would be fine with "coming soon", they don't seem to be about on-going construction once the site is live.

Comment: I would think "under construction" would be the most recognised term, considering it also features in most of the question titles listed? It probably also has the greatest historical significance IMO. However, "coming soon" is better English IMO. @StephenOstermiller "coming soon" just seems synonymous to me?

Comment: I have seen a lot of sites that have some content, but have "under construction" gifs in places where the author wants to make improvements.  In those cases the site is already there, not "coming soon".

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest creating the tag [coming-soon](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coming-soon) and tagging all the questions with that.

It sounds like a closer match to what the questions are about than "under construction" to me.  Under construction could also be about sites that need improvements.   It was very fashionable to put under construction gifs all over the site where it needed more work when the web was younger.   I don't currently see a need for a separate "under construction" tag based on the example questions you have found.

Because "under construction" is such a widely used term, I would suggest creating a tag synonym for it that points to [coming-soon](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coming-soon).  That would allow the coming soon tag to be found and used by people asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run a search on webmasters.exchange for the tags. If more people are putting "under construction" in their questions instead of the others, I would probably make that the tag. It's more likely that they would search for that as a tag if that's the keyword that they're using.

You could also do a search volume analysis on which keywords people are using most for the seo/programming/webmaster topic. If you target the most used keyword it might bring in more traffic.